# How to update TypeScript to specific version in my project angular with npm?

Tags: typescript, npm-install

In my package-lock.json of my project, I have Typescript  "typescript": "3.5.3", I want to update 4.0.2

How to do this with npm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your `package.json` file so that the line starting with `"typescript"` says `"typescript": "^4.0.2"`

Then run `npm install`